# How do you include flags when assigning a command to a variable

Tags: spring-batch

I would like to user the '/t' flag/option with the time command in command prompt.  However, when I assign the command to a variable and try to display the contents of the variable via the echo command, a string literal is displayed opposed to the output of the time command.

example:
set eTime=time /t
echo %eTime%

"eTime" is displayed, opposed to the local time.

Anyone have a tip or solution?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  But I suspect you want to use a step parameter.

Comment: echo %time% shows the contents of the time environment variable, which is the local time.  I want to assign the "time" COMMAND, to a variable, then reveal the contents of that variable via the echo command.